# Case When in where condition

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I can't seem to make my SP works:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestSP]
@participant_role nvarchar(max) = null,
@active int,
@inactive int
AS
BEGIN

select * from participant_list where participant_role = ISNULL(@participant_role, participant_role)

and 
case when @active = 0 then ((effective_end_date IS NULL) or (effective_end_date > CURRENT_DATE))

case when @inactive = 0 then ((effective_end_date IS NOT NULL) or (effective_end_date < CURRENT_DATE))

ELSE
--Return everything

END
```

What happen is, if the @active is 0, the query should include the condition `((effective_end_date IS NULL) or (effective_end_date > CURRENT_DATE))`

Like wise, if @inactive is 0, the condition should include `((effective_end_date IS NOT NULL) or (effective_end_date < CURRENT_DATE))`

And if both @active and @inactive are NOT 0, then it should return everything (no condition for this part). How do I make it work?

Comment: CASE is an expression that returns a single value, not a statement for  control-of-flow. http://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a particular affliction where people discover SQL's `CASE` expression and seem to immediately stop thinking about simpler boolean operators:

```
select * from participant_list
where participant_role = ISNULL(@participant_role, participant_role)
and
(
  (
     @active = 0 and (
        (effective_end_date IS NULL) or
        (effective_end_date > CURRENT_DATE)
     )
  ) or
  (
     @inactive = 0 and effective_end_date < CURRENT_DATE
  ) or
  ( @active = 1 and @inactive = 1)
)
```

Comment: You're right! Totally got hooked on the `CASE` and forgotten about the simple bool expression

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   ...
        AND
        CASE
        WHEN    @active = 0 AND ((effective_end_date IS NULL) or (effective_end_date > CURRENT_DATE)) THEN
                1
        WHEN    @inactive = 0 AND ((effective_end_date IS NOT NULL) or (effective_end_date < CURRENT_DATE)) THEN
                1
        ELSE
                1
        END = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, can you please explain what do all those 0 and 1 do?

Comment: I've tested the SP, it doesn't work. No matter `@active` and `@inactive` is 0 or 1, it will return everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from participant_list 
where participant_role = ISNULL(@participant_role, participant_role)
and 
(
  (@active = 0 and (effective_end_date IS NULL or effective_end_date > CURRENT_DATE))
 or
 (@inactive = 0 and (effective_end_date IS NOT NULL or effective_end_date < CURRENT_DATE))
 or 
  (@active != 0 and @active != 0)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

using case

```
    select * from participant_list 
    where (@participant_role IS NOT NULL AND participant_role = @participant_role)

and 1 = (case  when @active = 0 AND (effective_end_date IS NULL or (effective_end_date     > GETDATE())) 
then 1

 when @inactive = 0 AND (effective_end_date IS NOT NULL or (effective_end_date < GETDATE()) )
then 1

WHEN @active = 0 AND @inactive = 0 
THEN 1

else 0 end)
```